# Create ListBox MsgBox with Selected Items

Tags: ms-access, compiler-errors, listbox, vba, listboxitem

I have a listbox control that is suppose to populate a list of the items selected into a MsgBox, but I keep getting an error code when I run it.

**ERROR: Compile error: Method or data member not found**

What am I doing wrong?

```
Private Sub ctrSend_Click()
    Dim msg As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lstMsg As ListBox

    If lstShipping.ListIndex = -1 Then
        msg = "Nothing"
    Else
        msg = ""
        For i = 0 To lstShipping.ListCount - 1
            If lstShipping.Selected(i) Then _
                msg = msg & lstMsg.List(i) & vbCrLf
        Next i
    End If

    MsgBox "You selected: " & vbCrLf & msg, vbOKOnly, "Selected BIN"
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping on lstShipping, yet looking at items from lstMsg.  Is that really what you want to do?  If not, change lstMsg to lstShipping as below:

```
Private Sub ctrSend_Click()
  Dim msg As String
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim oItem as Variant
 ' Dim lstMsg As ListBox

 If lstShipping.ListIndex = -1 Then
   msg = "Nothing"
 Else
   msg = ""
   For Each oItem in lstShipping.ItemsSelected         
      msg = msg & lstShipping.ItemData(oItem) & vbCrLf   ' <---  lstShipping!         
   Next
 End If

 MsgBox "You selected: " & vbCrLf & msg, vbOKOnly, "Selected BIN"
 DoCmd.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: OK... when I do that I still get: **ERROR: Compile error: Method or data member not found** and it highlights .List in that same line.

Comment: I was working off of your original code, since I didn't have Access here.  Try this.  I'm not 100% sure .ListIndex = -1 will work on multiple selections, so test that.

Comment: Thank you so much for the assist, sorry for the late response. How hard would it be to send this information to a table instead of a msgbox?

Comment: Definitely possible.  Exactly how you would do it would depend on if the form is bound to the table you want to update with the shipping items or not.  Plus whether the selected items are going to multiple rows or columns.  I think big enough for another question with more explanation.  Thanks for the accept !